# Comparing nan (greater and greater equal)

Tags: c, compare, nan

I already know that `if(nan != nan) -> TRUE`, which is quite logical `(sqrt(-1)` has to be unequal to `0/0`).

The following line of code is also logical:

```
if(nan > 90.0f) -> FALSE
```

`...nan` is not a number, thus it cannot be greater or smaller than a number.

However, I do not understand why `if(nan >= 90.0f) -> TRUE` ?!?!

I'm using Tasking C166 compiler.

Comment: @Patashu c in the tags. I dont recall having used NAN in c tho ._.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly. I suspect the compiler "optimises" it to `if (!(nan < 90.0f))`. Since all comparisons [except `!=`] involving a NaN return false, that would cause the observed behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be a compiler bug[1].  You should report it to Tasking.

[1] From what I can see (http://www.tasking.com/products/c166/), Tasking does not claim conformance to IEEE-754, so this behavior may not actually be contrary to their published documentation.  It is, however, contrary to common sense and good taste.

Answer (score -3):

All i can say is that nan is probably represented by
01000010 10110100 00000000 00000000

If so, C will probably compare bit by bit and figure out that 90.0f is actually equal to nan.
Thats my only guess.

Edit: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point):
A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself. The comparison predicates are either signaling or non-signaling, the signaling versions signal an invalid exception for such comparisons. The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN. The other standard comparison predicates are all signaling if they receive a NaN operand, the standard also provides non-signaling versions of these other predicates. The predicate isNaN(x) determines if a value is a NaN and never signals an exception, even if x is a signaling NaN.

Ive just run the same line above in Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 and NAN >= 90.0f returned false.
Check if your compiler has fast-math option on, this may cause errors comparing NAN values.
in my math.h, NAN is defined in this way:

```
#define NAN (0.0F/0.0F)
```

Comment: If it would be bit-wise exactly the same, then how would you ever differentiate between the two? If anything, its exactly the opposite. Their bit pattern differ, however the built in routines do return something else.

Comment: nan is definitely not represented by 01000010 10110100 00000000 00000000 but by x1111111 1xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx1

Comment: I tried it on ideone and got "1.0/0.0>90.0f==true"so it's not just a problem with Rudi. It may be a problem with the compiler optimisations, but I'd like to see something about when the occur.

Comment: In my opinion 1.0/0.0 equals inf, and not nan...thus true is ok for this comparison.